# Get all the VBA macros of a workbook by EPPlus

Tags: epplus, epplus-4

In the sample `Sample15.cs` downloaded from [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/), I see that EPPlus can write/inject VBA macros. However, I don't see how to read all the VBA macros from a `.xlsm` workbook.

Can EPPlus interpret `VbaProject.bin` and support this functionality?

PS: it seems that `Open XML SDK` cannot do this either (please correct me if I am wrong), that's why I am considering EPPlus...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to read the code in each modules you just have to go through the 'Workbook.VbaProject.Modules' collection like this:

```
var fi = new FileInfo(@"C:\temp\Book1.xlsm");
using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(fi))
{
    var modules = pck.Workbook.VbaProject.Modules;
    foreach (var module in modules)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Module Name: {module.Name}{Environment.NewLine}Code:");
        Console.Write(module.Code);
        Console.WriteLine("---------");
    }
```

Which will give you this in the output (I just created an excel xlsm with two modules):

```
Module Name: ThisWorkbook
Code:
---------
Module Name: Sheet1
Code:
---------
Module Name: Module1
Code:
Public Sub proc1()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

    ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = "proc1"

End Sub

---------
Module Name: Module2
Code:
Public Sub proc2()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

    ws.Cells(2, 1).Value = "proc2"

End Sub

---------
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want... Additionally, I am investigating the source code of EEPlus to see how it achieves this... Why don't I see the interpretation of [vbaProject.bin](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/4/8/24862317-78f0-4c4b-b355-c7b2c1d997db/%5BMS-OVBA%5D.pdf)  in *VBA/*.cs`?

Comment: @SoftTimur I think manipulating the vba bin would be an entire project in itself since it is a binary file.  Since vba is kind of a subset/offshoot of the excel DOM it would really need a projects undivided attention to do it justice.  If you haven't seen this yet here is a good read:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15216/Office-bin-file-format

Comment: But your example shows that EEPlus does read this binary, right? though I don't see which part of its code achieves this...

Comment: @SoftTimur  That is true, Epplus does manipulate it for its own purposes but I am sure it is only a small fraction of what can be done.  But to answer you question, I believe the file `ExcelVbaProject.cs` is does the actual binary reading/writing http://epplus.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#EPPlus/VBA/ExcelVBAProject.cs  which is referenced in `ExcelWorkbook.cs`.